# Как в Laravel во время лоигна получить данные из $event?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.3. Моя задача сейчас состоит в том, чтобы поймать тот момент, когда происходит логин , когда пользователь прошел проверку на логин/пароль, и дополнительно проверить установлено ли значение в таблице active==0. Через Middleware не получается, он просто не хочет ни в какую. Решил делать через EventListener, удалось схватить этот момент и вывести данные по запрашиваемому пользователю. Остается както вытащить из объекта Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login $event id или active залогинившегося пользователя и принудительно сделать логаут если active не 1. Но я никак не пойму как вытащить из $event поле active. При попытке чтото взять он мне выдает TokenMismatchException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты пользуешься стандартной аутентификацией ? Попробуй переопределить метод в контроллере   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
}
```

или тут же сгенерировать свое событие

Как заметили в ответе ниже, есть еще такой метод, который тоже можно переопределить, добавив или изменив проверку:

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

Comment: Не знал про этот метод, спасибо попробую, чуть позже, потом отпишусь. Аутентификация вроде стандартная. Надо будет проверить

Comment: Сработало, благодарствую)

Comment: Вторым методом я пробовал ранее, но по нему никакой информации не нашел в документации, и что он делает так и не понял.

Comment: Получается можно использовать эти два метода, переопределяя в LoginController. Второй метод получается как я понял таким:

Comment: `protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password')+['active'=>true];
}`

Comment: Надо вторым попробовать, потому что первый все таки сначала залогинивает пользователя, а потом я его разлогиниваю, если условия не устраивают. В документации вообще пишут, что надо как-то через Middleware, потому что они как раз таки  и существуют для проверок перед тем как передать управление приложению. Хотя может это излишества. Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Если active=1 то вход иначе ошибка?

Решение вашей задачи:

Откройте **AuthenticatesUsers.php**

файл находиться в **vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth**

Найдите функцию **protected function credentials**

выглядит примерно так

```
return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
```

добавьте новое значение ['active'=>true] то есть поле active=1

```
return $request->only($this->username(), 'password')+['active'=>true];
```

И всё если пользователь активирован он войдёт в систему иначе нет.

Comment: Только можно просто этот метод переопределить, там же в  LoginController,  лезть в vendor не надо :)

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите пример, я тоже в будущем буду использовать Ваш пример чтобы в vendor не лезть. Спасибо.

Comment: Поправил свой ответ, посмотри, просто добавляешь этот метод в класс LoginController, дабы переопределить метод. Подробнее о переопределении в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php)